# Boot another OS while in Raspberry Pi Raspbian

Tags: operating-system, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, usb-drive

[image]

I have two OS's Raspbian and RetroPie. Both are store on two separate micro SD cards. I have a Retropie's SD card connected to a usb adapter. In the picture you can see that the file is right above the terminal window. Right now if I want to switch back and forth I have to take the Raspbian SD card out of my Raspberry Pi and put in the RetroPie's SD card. I'm wondering if there's a way that I can just boot it through Raspbian. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Raspberry Pi supports booting from USB but if you had a large enough SD card you could dual boot from the same SD card using NOOBS.

Answer (score 0):

You will find everything you need here : [HOW TO BOOT FROM A USB MASS STORAGE DEVICE ON A RASPBERRY PI3](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#usb-mass-storage-boot)
But you will always need an SD card at the beginning. I think some people booted pi1 and 2 with usb by putting special boot files into the SD card. Needless to say, it will be easier with a pi3 !